# Rss Parsing for Blackberry java

Tags: blackberry, java-me, rss

I have developed RssParser for Blackberry java and I successfully parsed titles  from Rss xml file, but my requirement is to parse also imageurls from Rss.

But my code is working fine for individual tags, my actual requirement is in the `drawlist` method. How to retrieve both image url and title tag values from Rss?

Here is my code:

```
public void run() {  
            Document doc;  
            StreamConnection conn = null; 
            InputStream is = null;  
            try {           

                conn = (StreamConnection) Connector.open("Rss.xml"+";deviceside=true");             

                DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
                docBuilderFactory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
                docBuilderFactory.setCoalescing(true);
                DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();    
                docBuilder.isValidating();      
                is = conn.openInputStream();    
                doc = docBuilder.parse(is);     
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();   


                   NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("image"); 

                NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("title"); 
                    for (int a = 0; a < list.getLength(); a++) {    
                    Node textNode1 = list.item(a).getFirstChild();  
                    listElements.addElement(textNode.getNodeValue());
                        }





public void drawListRow(ListField list, Graphics g, int index, int y, int w) 
    {  
         String title = (String)listElements.elementAt(index);


        g.drawText(title, 5, 15+y, 0, w);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code snipet will not compile because you have two "NodeList list" variables, but lets assume that you did get the images urls on a different list. For each url you need to fetch image data, initiate an Image object and store it for drawing later:

```
public void run() {
    NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("image");

    for (int a = 0; a < list.getLength(); a++) {
        Node textNode1 = list.item(a).getFirstChild();

        imageElements.addElement(getImage(textNode.getNodeValue()));
    }
}

// variation of the same method found at
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883600/how-do-i-get-to-load-image-in-j2me
private Image getImage(String url) throws IOException {
    HttpConnection connection = null;
    DataInputStream inp = null;
    int length;
    byte[] data;
    try {
        connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);
        connection.getResponseMessage();
        length = (int) connection.getLength();
        data = new byte[length];
        inp = new DataInputStream(connection.openInputStream());
        inp.readFully(data);

        return Image.createImage(data, 0, data.length);
    } finally {
        if (connection != null)
            connection.close();
        if (inp != null)
            inp.close();

    }
}

public void drawListRow(Graphics g, int index, int y, int w) {  
    String title = (String) listElements.elementAt(index);
    Image image = (Image) imageElements.elementAt(index);

    g.drawText(title, 5, 15+y, 0, w);
    // As I do not have experience with Blackberry I assume below method exists
    g.drawImage(image, 5, y, 0, w);
}
```